# how to get the mimeType from an application?

Tags: android, mime-types

How would i be able to get the mimeType from an application.

I am working on an application which filters certain installed applications based on the mimeType.

could someone please help me with this issue ?

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mime types are associated with activities. You can use List and PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0) to get all the activities and therefore applications for a given data mime type.

```
public static List<ResolveInfo> getIntents(String action, String category,
            PackageManager pm) {
        Intent i = new Intent(action, null);
        i.addCategory(category);
        i.setData(data_uri)
        List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        return list;
    }
```

Else, you can get all applications (Launchable) by:

getIntents(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT,Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER,pm);

and now classify by String type = getIntent().getType();

Comment: Hi sameer, can u give me an example.
like i want all the apps that have video mimeType.

Answer (score 0):

> How would i be able to get the mimeType from an application.

Applications do not have MIME types.

You can create an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` with some MIME type and use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to identify which activities will respond to that `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get MIME type of data in intent:

```
String type = getIntent().getType();
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a complete answer, this should help you get closer:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        //i.setData(Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo item : list){


            try {

                PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(item.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, pm.GET_SIGNATURES);
                Signature[] s = info.signatures;

                Log.d(LOG_TAG,item.activityInfo.name +":"+ s.toString());

            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(item.filter!=null){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,item.activityInfo.name + ": " + item.filter.toString());
                List<String> types = (List<String>) item.filter.typesIterator();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I used this code to get all the mimetypes. but i am getting nullpointer as the variable item.filter is always null in both simulator and also in device.